# Azure Form Recognizer How Can I Get an Output That Looks Like the Studio?

Tags: azure-form-recognizer

I am using "prebuilt-layout" for the Form Recognizer:

```
    AnalyzeDocumentOperation operation = await client.AnalyzeDocumentAsync(WaitUntil.Completed, "prebuilt-layout", stream);
AnalyzeResult result = operation.Value;
```

This works fine and I get my result.

The issue is that tables/paragraphs are not within the "pages" response.

So data in "tables" will also appear in "paragraphs".

So if I want to rebuild Page 1, I need to parse through all the paragraphs, and see if they appear in the table, and then remove the paragraphs that do, which is brittle and prone to error.

Is there any setting I could provide so the results returned are the actual "layout" of the PDF document?

[image]

In the studio you can see paragraphs, then tables, with no over lap. That is the type of output I am looking for.